# How to calculate the area of a layer in centimeters using photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I want to calculate the size of a layer area in centimeters using photoshop. Is there any tool to do so rather than the ruler? The layer I need to calculate the size of its area doesn't have a proper shape.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I must say it's an interesting question though. It would be easy to write a program to do this, if the layer were a separate image in a standard format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a selection and there is a INFO tab where you can see the size. You have to set the unit to centimeters in Preferences -> Units (pixels is the default setting).

[image]